# Using TheCallingAssembly or AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory and WithDefaultConditions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Today I have been trying to set up the simplest possible usage of `structureMap` version 3.1.0.133 in a Windows console app.

I'm having trouble getting the `WithDefaultConventions` method working like I believe it should. I have a `Member` class that implements an `IMember` interface.  `StructureMap` registers `Member` concrete class as expected using explicit `cfg.For<>..Use<>`, but I must be missing something in setting up the `.WithDefaultConventions`.

```
    private void Init()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Scan(scan =>
            {
                //scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();

                // named assembly not found ?
                //scan.Assembly("myApp");
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });

            //cfg.For<IMember>().Use<Member>();
     }
```

Without .For<>, this line results in error

```
IMember member = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IMember>();
```

How can I get StructureMap to "see" the calling assembly and perform convention based registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() to see currently loaded assemblies contains "MyApp"

You may also try this:

1. Add a class library project to your solution ("Models")
2. Move your "IMember" and "Member" (and delete from console project)
3. Add a reference to "Models" in your console project.
4. Then use

`scan.Assembly("Models");`

in your initialize routine.

This is an application structure that might be closer to what you would use in production anyway.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks - this worked like a charm. But I still dont know why TheCallingAssembly didnt find the classes in the scan of the same interface/class.

Comment: Did you see the assembly you had originally tried when you used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() ?

Comment: using System.Reflection; var assms = Appdomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); foreach(asm in assms) { Debug.Writeline(asm,FullName); }

Answer (score -1):

Also, ensure that you do not use an extension in string  referencing assembly name